# Repeat Customers being counted more than once BigQuery & Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I am working with BigQuery and Google Data Studio. I want to count the number of repeat customers and the repeat purchase rate(repeat customer/totalcustomers) in a chosen date range. The date range is a filter on my data studio dashboard.

Example Dataset
[image: dataset]

Date Range Filter selected : Jan 1 2020 to September 30 2020

Output I want

[image: output wanted]

Output I am Getting

[image: output being produced]

This is the code I have so far

```
    with ct as(
    select order_id, customer_id, order_date, first_order_date, 
    case when datediff(order_date, first_order_date,Day)!=0 
    then 1 else 0 end as ret_flag 
    from xx
    )
    
    select order_date, 
count(distinct(case when return_flag=0 then customer_id end)) as new_customer
    count(distinct(case when return_flag=1 then customer_id end)) as return_Customer
        
    from ct 
    group by order_date
```

Comment: Adding some sample data would greatly help your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Date Range Filter is dynamically selected by a user this logic should be not in the query but in the Dashboard itself. Use your Example Dataset as the datasource for the dashboard as is.Then in the Dashboard click `Resource -> Manage added datasources` and `EDIT` your datasource. Click `ADD A FIELD` and apply your logic `COUNT_DISTINCT(CASE ... END)`